# Recursion and Tuples in Python

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I am trying to write two functions that take an integer and return a tuple. I can get very close to what would like to return, but what I am returning has multiple parenthesis within it. for example, I want rec_range(5) to return (0,1,2,3,4) instead of (((((0, 1), 2), 3), 4).

Here are the two functions I am writing

```
def rec_range(n):
    '''Takes a natural number n and returns a tuple of numbers starting
       with 0 and ending before n.
       Int-->Tuple'''

    if n == 0:
         return 
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n >= 1:
        return rec_range(n-1),(n-1)

def squares_tuple(n,m):
    '''Takes a natural numbers n and m and returns a tuple of the squares
       of all the natural numbers starting with n and ending with m-1.
       Int,Int-->Tuple'''

    while n<=m:
        return n * n, squares_tuple(n + 1, m)
```

Comment: Also, I do not want to use range(), map(), loops, or lists.

Comment: yes but I would like to know why I am getting what I am getting.

Comment: This is not a good use-case for recursion

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're using the return value from your recursive calls as a single element in a new tuple, rather than constructing a tuple from the elements in the return value plus new elements.

Instead, you should probably be adding tuples together:

```
return rec_range(n-1) + (n-1,)
```

and

```
return (n*n,) + squares_tuple(n+1, m)
```

Note that doing this means that your functions need to always return a tuple (which is probably a good thing, because sometimes returning one data type and sometimes another is a good way to create runtime errors), so you need to adjust some of your other non-recursive returns as well - for instead, instead of `return 0` you'd want to use `return (0,)`.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues: first, you need to return a tuple, rather than an int, for your base case:

```
if n == 1:
    return (0,)
```

Second, you need to append `n - 1` to the tuple rather than return it as a pair with the tuple:

```
if n >= 1:
    return rec_range(n-1) + (n-1,)
```

Your `squares_tuple` can be solved by a similar approach. Note that I changed the base case to return an empty tuple rather than `None`. (I also changed `while` to `if`, which makes it a bit clearer since it happens only once).

```
if n<=m:
    return (n * n,) + squares_tuple(n + 1, m)
return ()
```